# Major developer highlights in winter 17?

Tags: winter17

What are the major highlights for developers in winter 17?

**P.S. I'm not just talking about Lightning experience**

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit too broad I think, the easiest answer is simply to look at the [release notes](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/204/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_winter17_release_notes.pdf).